# NPLB crash in SbBlitterDestroySwapChain with cobalt

Tags: cobalt

When run NPLB test, it will crash as follows in `starboard/shared/directfb/blitter_destroy_swap_chain.cc` because of the directfb surface is not created when it used openGL(not directfb) to draw the UI, so this directfb test case may need to be skiped when it uses openGL. If it's so, is there a plan to skip the directfb related test cases when it uses the openGL to draw the UI?

```
Caught signal: SIGSEGV (11)
        SbBlitterDestroySwapChain [0x1ae304]
        SbBlitterDestroySwapChain [0x1ae304]
        SbBlitterDestroySwapChain [0x1ae304]
        SbBlitterDestroySwapChain [0x1ae304]
        SbBlitterDestroySwapChain [0x1ae304]
        SbBlitterDestroySwapChain [0x1ae304]
        SbBlitterDestroySwapChain [0x1ae304]
        SbBlitterDestroySwapChain [0x1ae304]
        SbBlitterDestroySwapChain [0x1ae304]
        SbBlitterDestroySwapChain [0x1ae304]
```

Comment: Blitter tests will run only if SB_HAS_BLITTER is 1. Does your configuration_public.h has SB_HAS_BLITTER set to 0? (I assume your gyp_configuration.gypi has 'gl_type': 'system_gles2').

Comment: hi mmotorny, yes, we set gl_type to use opengl, and it does not use directfb blitter(SB_HAS_BLITTER  is used for directFB), so gl_type and SB_HAS_BLITTER  should be mutually exclusive, if so, it maybe better  to set SB_HAS_BLITTER automatically based on the setting of gl_type, is it?

Comment: hi mmotorny, if I set SB_HAS_BLITTER 0, data structures in starboard/blitter.h will be disabled, but lots of places still referenced it, then lots of blitter related build errors would happen.

Comment: This is certainly not expected. Can you give an example of code that refers to blitter despite SB_HAS_BLITTER set to 0?

Comment: hi, mmotomy, I used cobalt 9.34413, when set SB_HAS_BLITTER to 0,  some errors messages from starboard/shared/directfb/blitter_internal.h said 'SbBlitterSurfaceInfo/SbBlitterColor/SbBlitterRect/SbBlitterContext...' are not named a type or declared, these data structures are defined in starboard/blitter.h which is disabled by setting SB_HAS_BLITTER to 0.

Comment: The whole file of blitter.h is defined as follows:
 #if SB_HAS(BLITTER) ....  #endif  // SB_HAS(BLITTER)

Comment: You probably include files from "starboard/shared/directfb" in your starboard_platform.gypi. Either remove them or include them conditionally based on 'gl_type'.

Comment: Hi, mmotomy, yes, it need to include them conditionally based on 'gl_type', thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are including files from `starboard/shared/directfb` in your `starboard_platform.gypi` on a platform that supports OpenGL ES. You need to include sources conditionally based on `'gl_type'`:

```
'conditions': [
  ['gl_type == "none"', {
    'sources': [
      # Blitter source files.
    ],
  }, {
    'sources': [
      # OpenGL ES source files.
    ],
  }],
],
```

See `src\cobalt\renderer\backend\starboard\platform_backend.gyp` for a real-life example.